# Converting a pandas dataframe column in "Wed May 27 07:13:23 EDT 2020" format to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I convert an object column in "Wed May 27 07:13:23 EDT 2020" format to datetime in pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can just let Pandas try:

```
pd.to_datetime(['Wed May 27 07:13:23 EDT 2020'])
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-27 07:13:23-04:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)]', freq=None)
```